# zsh:abort message after all the program has been run?

Tags: c, memory-management

So I am running this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAYSIZE 17
#define NUMTHREADS 4

struct ThreadData {
  int start, stop;
  int *array;
};

void squarer(struct ThreadData *data) {
  int start = data->start;
  int stop = data->stop;
  int *array = data->array;
  int i;
  for (i=start; i<stop;i++) {
    array[i] = i*i;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int array[ARRAYSIZE];
  int i, start, stop;
  struct ThreadData *data;
  data->array = array;
  int tasksPerThread = (ARRAYSIZE+NUMTHREADS-1)/NUMTHREADS;


  for (i=0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++) {
    start = i * tasksPerThread;
    stop = (i+1) * tasksPerThread;
    data->start = start;
    data->stop = stop;

    if (stop > ARRAYSIZE) {
      stop = ARRAYSIZE;
    }
    squarer(data);
  }
  for (i=0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And for some reason if give me the error message `zsh:abort  ./thread` when I run it. The funny thing is though that it doesn't abort until after the array has been fully printed? I don't understand why this is, surely it can't access out of bounds memory after it's executed everything? Note that originally the printf loop printed out array items but I changed it to bug check and it is still giving me the same run time error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was basically the edge case condition for the stop variable was defined below where the edge case was passed into the struct so the stop value could be large than the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAYSIZE 17
#define NUMTHREADS 4

struct ThreadData {
  int start, stop;
  int *array;
};

void squarer(struct ThreadData *data) {
  int start = data->start;
  int stop = data->stop;
  int *array = data->array;
  int i;
  for (i=start; i<stop;i++) {
    printf("%d %d\n",start,stop);
    array[i] = i*i;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int array[ARRAYSIZE];
  int i, start, stop;
  struct ThreadData data;
  data.array = array;
  int tasksPerThread = (ARRAYSIZE+NUMTHREADS-1)/NUMTHREADS;


  for (i=0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++) {
    start = i * tasksPerThread;
    stop = (i+1) * tasksPerThread;
    data.start = start;
    if (stop >= ARRAYSIZE) {
      break;
    }
    data.stop = stop;

    squarer(&data);
  }
  for (i=0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
  }
 return 0;
}
```

I borrowed code from some of the other answers

Answer (score 1):

In function `main`, variable `data` is not initialized. You are most likely performing a memory access violation whenever you use this variable, so everything that happens is pretty much "a matter of luck".

You must fix it **to begin with**:

```
struct ThreadData* data = (struct ThreadData*)malloc(sizeof(struct ThreadData));
...
free(data); // at the end of the program
```

Another option (a better one in this case) is to use a statically-allocated instance instead:

```
struct ThreadData data;
...
squarer(&data);
```

**Now, the problem with your array is the indexing.**

Change:

```
array[i] = i*i
```

To:

```
array[i-start] = i*i
```

BTW, I strongly recommend that you either declare `int array[ARRAYSIZE]` **inside** your `ThreadData` structure, or allocate it dynamically in every function that uses this structure (instead of setting `array` to point to a local array in function `main`). It **will** become a problem as soon as you start using this structure in several places.

Comment: I tried both of your edits and I still get the same error. Is there any other reason I might get this error?

Comment: Your solution wasn't right but it did help me get to the right solution so thanks! Posting the solution to the problem momentarily.

Comment: Not sure what your solution is, but you still must replace `array[i]` with `array[i-start]`, as I mention in the answer.

Comment: Your solution prevents the memory error but it doesn't get the correct solution at the end. As I mentioned in my question, the array items are the data it should be computing not the i value. So your solution does print the same result but the values in the array are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3rd line in main is not okay, i.e. undefined:

```
struct ThreadData *data;
data->array = array;
```

because data is not initialized in the second line, right? `data` is pointing *anywhere*...

```
struct ThreadData *data = (struct ThreadData*) malloc(sizeof(struct ThreadData));
```

might help.